# Two parts, consolidate Column A while adding corresponding values from Column B

Tags: excel

I am trying to add values in Column B based on data in Column A.  Additionally I am looking to remove duplicates from Column A in a separate output on another sheet.  Here is how the data looks:

[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuyFz.png)

I've tried SUMIF and VLOOKUP based on some similar posts but neither have worked.  I know I could use remove duplicates manually but would like to have a formula solution such that the data is automatically consolidated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you consolidate the left-hand column manually, i.e. as a one-time thing?  It would make it really easy to supply the totals then with `sumif()`.

Comment: Yea I think so Marc, thanks for trying to help.  I just found one solution using SUMIF to calculate values for Column B and then manually removed duplicates in both column A and B, leaving me with the desired solution.  I was hoping to find a more elegant answer though, one that did not require manually input :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using formula to avoid manual consolidation, try the below set of formulas

In the cell A2, enter the below formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:$F$7, MATCH(0, INDEX(COUNTIF($A$1:A1, $F$2:$F$7), 0, 0), 0)), "")
```

In the cell B2, enter the below formula

```
=if(A2="","",SUMIF($F$2:$F$7,A2,$G$2:$G$7))
```

The $F$2:$F$7 and $G$2:$G$7 references in the above formulas are the data. If it is from different sheet, then you may need to replace these accordingly.

Once you enter the same in A2 and B2, copy the same in rest of the rows, and you will get what you want.

Comment: Thank you Karpak!